# Magento 2 + UI Component don't get value in post

Tags: magento2

I am using htmlContent in Ui Component form. When i submit form i didn't get data in post which are using in htmlConent.

My Code is : request_form.xml

```
    <fieldset name="request_item">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="enduser_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="request_price_items">
            <!--<argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Extendway\Requestquote\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Requestproduct</argument>-->
            <block class="Extendway\Requestquote\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Requestproduct" name="item_info" ></block>
        </htmlContent>

    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Template File is

```
<input type="text" name="quote_id" value="XXXX" />
```

I am not getting "quote_id" in Post data.

Please help what i am missing in HtmlConent & Ui Component file.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this attribute `data-form-part="form-name"` to your input.
Please change the `form-name` with your form name